# Jersey warning - Not resolvable to a concrete type

Tags: java, spring, generics, jersey, warnings

I am using Jersey `1.19` for Rest APIs. One of my resources class has a setter method as follow:

```
private Registrar<String, EventBatchDeserializer<?>> versionedDeserializer;

public void setVersionedDeserializer(Registrar<String, EventBatchDeserializer<?>> versionedDeserializer) 
{
    this.versionedDeserializer = versionedDeserializer;
}
```

Registrar class is as follows:

```
public class Registrar<K, V>
{
private ConcurrentHashMap<K, V> registeredItems;

public Registrar()
{
    this.registeredItems = new ConcurrentHashMap<K, V>();
}

public void register(K key, V value)
{
    registeredItems.put(key, value);
}

public V getRegisteredItem(K key)
{
    return registeredItems.get(key);
}
}
```

Now, I am creating the registar object and injecting it into this resource class as:

```xml
<bean id="versionedDeserializer" class="a.b.c.d.Registrar">
    </bean>


<property name="versionedDeserializer" ref="versionedDeserializer" />
```

Now, the problem is Jersey giving the warning on the setter that is being used injecting the registrar, that `Parameter 1 of that setter is not resolvable to a concrete type.

I am using Tomcat 8.0 for the webapp. Can anyone please let me know why am I receiving this warning, and what is the resolution?

Answer (score 0):

The warning should go away if you replace the wildcard in the type parameter of `EventBatchDeserializer` with a concrete type, for example the method signature could look like this:

```
public void setVersionedDeserializer(Registrar<String, EventBatchDeserializer<Foo>> versionedDeserializer)
```

Obviously this is more restrictive than a wildcard. Maybe you could use a `Foo` interface. If only a wildcard fits your needs, I guess you have to live with the warning. If everything works as expected, there’s probably no harm in ignoring it.