# jersey warning "is not resolvable to a concrete type" on generic <?> type

Tags: java, generics, jersey-2.0

I'm using *Jersey 2.25* and *Google Guava BiMap* within my service. I have declared a member variable of my webservice class with `BiMap<String, myClass<? >>`.
After my Jetty server starts I get the warning:

> WARNING: Parameter 1 of type `com.google.common.collect.BiMap<java.lang.String, myClass<?>>` from `public myProvider(com.google.common.collect.BiMap<java.lang.String, myClass<?>>`) is not resolvable to a concrete type.

I cannot remove the `<?>` operator, because some elements of myClass will not resolved correctly without the `<?>` operator. I have also tried a facade pattern, but within the pattern I need the `<?>` operator also.

How can I fix this warning?

Comment: Seems like the same as [Jersey warning - Not resolvable to a concrete type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31204634/jersey-warning-not-resolvable-to-a-concrete-type).